# Parfor-loop not working, how to fix?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, parallel-processing

I am trying to parallize two of my for-loops and run it on a remote cluster.

I am using matlabpool open local 12 at the beginning with matlabpool close at the end. The problem I am running into is that my parfor-loop cannot use my matric properly and I am not sure how I would rewrite it so that it works.

```
H = hadamard(n);
H = [H;-H];
P = setdiff(P,H,'rows');
[r,c] = size(P);
A = zeros(n,r);
  parfor i=1:r
      for j=1:n
          d = P(i,:) + H(j,:);
          A(j,i) = sum(d(:) ~= 0);
      end
  end
```

and:

```
u2Had = cell(2,r);
parfor i =1:r
    u2Had{1,i} = min(A(:,i));
    MinHadIndex = find(A(:,i) == u2Had{1,i});
    u2Had{2,i} = MinHadIndex;
end
```

Those are the two segments of the code I am trying to parallize. Any help is much appreciated and if I need to add anymore information please ask.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your problem is in the first part as it works fine (perhaps if you defined P better)

regarding the second part, you can only send information to and from parloops in narrow cases.

Here change your code to the following:

```
u2HadT = cell(1,r);

parfor i =1:r
    temp = min(A(:,i));
    MinHadIndex = find(A(:,i) == temp);
    u2HadT{i} = {temp;MinHadIndex};   
end
u2Had = cell(2,r);
for i =1:r
    u2Had{1,i} = u2HadT{i}(1);
    u2Had{2,i} = u2HadT{i}(2);
end
```